# Formatting combined numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, format, numbers

I have a table of data in Excel which has wind direction in one column and wind speed in another. I want to combine the wind speed and direction and then format it.

So for example

| WD | WS | COMBINED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 050 | 12.23 | 50 12.23 |
| 360 | 21.54 | 360 21.54 |

I need the combined data to look like: 050 12 and 360 21

I combined the data in a new column. I cannot format the numbers how I need them.

```vb
Public Sub CombineWind()

    Dim xy As Worksheet

    Set xy = Worksheets("combine")
    Dim LRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns(8).Insert
        xy.Range("H3:H" & LRow).Formula = "=B3 & "" "" & C3"
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns(9).Insert
        xy.Range("I3:I" & LRow).Formula = "=D3 & "" "" & E3"
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns(10).Insert
        xy.Range("J3:J" & LRow).Formula = "=F3 & "" "" & G3"
    End With

    Range("H2") = "Average"
    Range("I2") = "Min"
    Range("J2") = "Max"
End Sub
```

Comment: _I need the combined data to look like: 050 12 or 360 21_ - but your table shows differently for column _Combined_, so what to believe?

Comment: To output a number as a string use the Format() function, like `Format(50, "000")`. You can then concatenate that string with another that might possibly have been created in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below, while not ready to paste and perform, should help you on your way.

```
Dim Arr As Variant

With ActiveSheet
    ' take the value of a range from A1 to end x 7 columns
    Arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 7).Value
End With

With xy
    For R = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(R, "H").Value = Format(Arr(3, 2), "000 ") & Format(Arr(3, 3), "hh:mm")
    Next R
End With
```

The use of `ActiveSheet` is always dangerous. Better name the sheet in the code.

The snippet above reads the enter sheet into an array. The important thing is to start the array in A1 so that Arr(1, 1) = A1 and, therefore, Arr(3, 2) = B3. It's easy to read without further help.

`.Cells(R, "H")` identifies the correct cell to set the `Value` property of but `Format(Arr(3, 2), "000 ") & Format(Arr(3, 3), "hh:mm")` only specifies B3 and C3 of the taken array which must be made dynamic by probably making only the row numbers adjust in some relationship to `R`. The point is to show how to set the value of the "Combined" column.

Comment: Hi Variatus, thanks for your suggestion. I will try that. I have also found the CONCATENATE function which works on an individual cell within the spreadsheet. However, when I try and use it within my code to automatically do all the rows it says "Expected end of statement".

Dim xy As Worksheet

Set xy = Worksheets("combine")
Dim LRow As Long


With ActiveSheet
      LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns(9).Insert
        xy.Range("I3:I" & LRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(TEXT(B5,"000")," ",TEXT(C5,"00")," ","G"," ",TEXT(G5,"00"))"
    End With

Comment: When you want to include quotation marks in a quotation you must write a double-quotation mark between quotation marks. Try `? """"` in the Immediate pane. I don't understand if the "G" in your formula is a variable or a letter but presuming that it's a letter (string) perhaps this is the formula you want to assign. `"=CONCATENATE(TEXT(B5,""000 ""),TEXT(C5,""00 ""),""G "",TEXT(G5,""00""))"`. Observe that I have included the spaces you wish to insert in the masks for the TEXT functions to avoid a flood of inverted commas.

Comment: That has done the trick! Thanks very much for your help. I have nearly completed my project :)

Comment: Great! Only thing remaining now is to mark the answer as "Selected". Thank you.